# Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

```
function unzipCode() {
    console.log('Unzipping contents...');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const files = [];
      unzip.open(filePath, { autoclose: false, lazyEntries: true }, (err, zipfile) => {
        if (err) reject;
        zipfile.readEntry();
        zipfile.on('entry', (entry) => {
          if (!sourceDirectoryRegEx.test(entry.fileName)) {
            console.log("  [X] Skipping: " + entry.fileName);
            zipfile.readEntry();
          }
          else {
            console.log("  [+] Unzipping: " + entry.fileName);
            if (/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {
              // directory file names end with '/'
              mkdirp(path.join(cwd, entry.fileName), (err) => {
                if (err) reject;
                zipfile.readEntry();
              });
            }
            else {
              zipfile.openReadStream(entry, (err, readStream) => {
                if (err) reject;
                // ensure parent directory exists
                mkdirp(path.join(cwd, path.dirname(entry.fileName)), (err) => {
                  if (err) reject;
                  let stream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(cwd, entry.fileName));

                  readStream.pipe(stream, { end: false });

                  //    console.log(readStream.pipe);
                  readStream.on('end', () => {
                    console.log('After write', entry.fileName);
                    // add file details to files array
                    files.push({
                      key: entry.fileName,
                      body: stream,
                    });
                    zipfile.readEntry();

                    readStream.unpipe(stream);
                    stream.end();
                  });
                });
              });
            }
          }
        });
        zipfile.once('end', () => {
          zipfile.close();
          resolve(files);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I am trying to unzip some files in aws-lambda console using the function. The enviornment I've chosen is nodejs 12.x. It was running with nodejs 8.10. 

The exact error I'm encountering is **Cannot pipe, not readable**.

How to solve it?

Comment: can you share more details like at which line you are getting this error? also, what is unzip? is it some external npm package?

Comment: "unzip" is actually an instance of yauzl module. However, I really cannot say which line is causing the error.